# Compare each element of a list in existing order with elements of a second list in order as long as items in lists are equal

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

Compare each element of a list in existing order with elements of a second list in existing order as long as items in lists are equal. Stop if they're not equal and give me as result the index and name of the last match.

I thought it's straightforward with a while loop but it seems like this has to be approached with a for-loop.

**My List one I want to compare:**
**nk_script_file_path**

```
['P:', 'Projects', '2019_projects', '1910_My_Project', '01_Production_IN', '01_OFX', '01_Comp', '00_Nuke', 'relink_test_v001.nk']
```

**My second list I want to compare it to:**
**node_filepath**

```
['P:', 'Projects', '2019_projects', '1910_My_Project', '02_Production_OUT', '01_OFX', '01_Comp', '00_Nuke', '040_ALY', '040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE', '040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_Gamma22_apcs_mov', '040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_v14_Gamma22_apcs.mov']
```

**What I've tried**

```
nk_script_file_path = r"P:/Projects/2019_projects/1910_My_Project/01_Production_IN/01_OFX/01_Comp/00_SO/relink_test_v001.nk".split("/")
node_filepath = r"P:/Projects/2019_projects/1910_My_Project/02_Production_OUT/01_OFX/01_Comp/00_S=/040_ALY/040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE/040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_Gamma22_apcs_mov/040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_v14_Gamma22_apcs.mov".split("/")

# Compare file paths
path_object = 0
while nk_script_file_path in node_filepath:
    path_object += 1
print path_object
print node_filepath[path_object]
```

**Result I'm looking for:**

```
"3"
```

or

```
"1910_My_Project"
```

Comment: `while nk_script_file_path in node_filepath:` this doesn't iterate both lists at once. Use `for` loop with `zip`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip()` with `enumerate()` to find first index where's difference. In this example if no difference is found, value of `i` is equal to `-1`:

```
lst1 = ['P:', 'Projects', '2019_projects', '1910_My_Project', '01_Production_IN', '01_OFX', '01_Comp', '00_Nuke', 'relink_test_v001.nk']
lst2 = ['P:', 'Projects', '2019_projects', '1910_My_Project', '02_Production_OUT', '01_OFX', '01_Comp', '00_Nuke', '040_ALY', '040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE', '040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_Gamma22_apcs_mov', '040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_v14_Gamma22_apcs.mov']


for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lst1, lst2)):
    if a != b:
        break
else:
    i = -1

print('First difference is at index:', i)
```

Prints:

```
First difference is at index: 4
```

Comment: This does *not* return -1 for failure; you changed `i` in the loop.  Rather, it returns the lesser of the two lengths.  In a way, this *is* the position of the first difference, either an element compared to nothing, or a vacuous non-match.

Comment: @Prune You have right, nothing is returned here, I reworded it slightly.

Comment: Your description is incorrect.  The only way you can return -1 is if one of the lists is empty, such that the loop is never entered.

Comment: @Prune Now should be ok. I added `else` to `for`, if there isn't any match, `i` is set to `-1`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thank you a lot for your great input. It looks great but is not returning "3". Instead it returns "4". `i = 0` gives me the exact same result as `i = -1`

Comment: @BenjaminK: well, if the first difference is at position `k`, how do you get the index of the position just before that?

Comment: @BenjaminK You can subtract 1 if there's a difference and you get position where the lists are the same (of course, it needs special handling if there's a difference at position `0`).

Comment: @AndrejKesely Yes, I could subtract 1 :) just wanted to clarify it for your answer. The first match is always the same I have some code before that, that is making sure this is the case. Again thank you for your help. Why is it that -1 and 0 gives the same result?

Answer (score 0):

```
nk_script_file_path= r"P:/Projects/2019_projects/1910_My_Project/01_Production_IN/01_OFX/01_Comp/00_SO/relink_test_v001.nk".split("/")
node_filepath = r"P:/Projects/2019_projects/1910_My_Project/02_Production_OUT/01_OFX/01_Comp/00_S=/040_ALY/040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE/040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_Gamma22_apcs_mov/040_ALY_040_HROTERRORBLADE_prev_v14_Gamma22_apcs.mov".split("/")
j = 0
for i in nk_script_file_path:
    if i != node_filepath[j] :
        j = j-1
        break
    else:
        j += 1

print(nk_script_file_path[j])
print(j)
```